# Royal Slider slow down Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

I´m working on a Wordpress website, we decided to use Royal Slider plugin.

The plugin is not purchased yet, we tested to verify that it would be a good option and everything was fine. But we moved to a new server before the oficial launch of the page.
 The website is very slow (about 60 seconds) when the plugin is enabled, if it is disabled the page load very fast (500 ms).

We removed the scripts and css files for the plugin from the header to verofy that is not a jquery file conflict, and it takes the same long time, even when nothing from the plugin is loaded. No error is shown on console log.

Is the new server the problem?
Should we purchase to avoid the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The same problem I have faced by shifting my website to the new server. Before shifting to the new server the score of my website was 98 for desktop and 95 for mobile in Google Page Speed Insights. But as after successfully shifted to the new server the score was reduced to 38 and 42 so, started the website optimization again on the new server and now it's bit increased to 58 and 62. But as you mentioned that no error is showing for your website, I think you should manually Minify CSS, javascript and do one thing that check your website score to [Google page speed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) only, don't rely on any other tool which gives random results.

Comment: i can´t use Google, the page take more than 60 seconds to load and causes timeout

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of carousel-style plugins out there, and they all have various strengths and weaknesses. However, RoyalSlider (License: Commercial, CodeCanyon: RoyalSlider, Price: $12) by Dmitry Semenov is a responsive, touch-enabled, jQuery image gallery and content slider plugin, and is one of the slickest I've seen. The author has worked hard to ensure it's fast and efficient -- it features smart lazy loading, hardware accelerated CSS3 transitions, and a memory management algorithm that ensures only visible slides are in the DOM at any one time.

The plugin is actively maintained, and has seen over a dozen updates since its release in August 2011. It's distributed exclusively through CodeCanyon, but Dmitry's site also has documentation and details on WordPress integration. Purchasing RoyalSlider gives access to a set of RoyalSlider templates that includes several types of galleries that should slot right in to your projects.
http://smallenvelop.com/free-lms-learning-management-system-wordpress-plugins/